# How can I change the default browser loaded from SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, browsers

If I am in SharePoint Designer 2010 and select an item in a folder, and press F12, IE automatically pops up.  I would like it to be Chrome.  How can I adjust this setting in SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the ribbon, via "Preview in Browser"

[image]

Comment: I did that and set the checkbox only for Chrome and the correct browser path.  I then hit ok, went back to my file, hit F12, but IE still shows up.    I also went into Chrome's settings and made it my default browser.  This is odd...

Comment: Crap then, that is your only way via SharePoint Designer that I know, also explained here  http://aaclage.blogspot.ch/2011/10/add-multiple-browsers-preview-in.html. Unless you find something in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

for those who still needs a solution.

1. Follow the steps provided by Marius. (Click Preview in Browser -> Edit Browser List -> Add... -> Add... -> Provide Name (Can be any)-> Command (Provide path to chrome.eexe; use 'Browse...' if needed)
2. Now, click again 'Preview in Browser' in the ribbon then in the dropdown list, select the one for your Chrome. (Refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuNjf.jpg)

Cya